# Jupyter Notebook Can't Install Plugins

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm running python 3.12.2 on windows and used pip to install jupyter notebook. I can't seem to install any extensions in the extension manager or by the command line. In the jupyter notebook extension manager I get a message like

```
Error when performing an action.

Reason given:

Error: ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp_ke3m9q8'
```

every time I attempt to install a listed extension. I can't get any hits on this error via google search, and I tried a couple other ways to install plugins as well (I'd like to install the varInspector plugin or up to date equivalent).